# How to set the input type date to null after submitting the form using React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem on my text field input type date, I want to set all the input date to null after I submit the inputted data. I don't understand why this input type date still the value set on the input. currently I am using React Js Library and Backend is Laravel and Redux for state management.

My Questions:

1. How to set it on null value after I submit the form.
2. Why other input data the value was clear already after I submit the form.

Note: No error found

Scenario:

First: Inputted data inside the modal.

[image]

Second: After I submit it. this is what happen if I click the add new data.

[image: second scenario]

Now, I will share my code to you guys so that you will understand well the problem.

HandleSubmit:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {

    
    console.log(this.state.rows);
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addReceiveCheck(this.state.rows)
    this.loadingSwal()

}
```

JSX:

```
 <input type="date" value={selected_check_dates} name="date" onChange={e => this.handleCheckDateChange(e, i)} className="form-control" style={{border:'none'}}/>
```

HandlerDateChange:

```
handleCheckDateChange = (e, index) => { 

    const {name, value} = e.target;

    const list = [...this.state.rows];
    const list_date = this.state.selected_check_dates;
    list[index]['checkDate'] = value; 

    this.setState({
        selected_check_dates: value

    })


}
```

Actual Output:

[image: actual Output]

Expected Output: The check date input date also will be on null after I submit the form.

Comment: We need to see the function responsible for clearing your inputs.

Comment: How are you rendering these values here? Your backend most likely adding the date by default.

Comment: @fortunee no, that is inputted date.

Comment: Ok, I see the JSX for the input, but what about the JSX for displaying these values

Comment: @fortunee what do you mean for what about the JSX for displaying these values

Comment: Ok nvm, I get it now, what is the default value of `selected_check_dates`?

Comment: @fortunee i set it on my state as selected_check_dates:null

Comment: But you're resetting it to `value` which has a date. `this.setState({
        selected_check_dates: value
    })`

Comment: @fortunee so what suppost to be?

Comment: See my answer, I hope it helps